# Saving two lists to xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a list called "Preke" and I'm saving it with current code:

```
public void saveToXML()
{
    var xEle = new XElement("Prekes",
        from prk in PrekiuListas
        select new XElement("Preke",
            new XAttribute("Name", prk.name),
            new XElement("Price", prk.price),
            new XElement("Description", prk.description),
            new XElement("Category", prk.category)
        )); 
 }
```

I also have public `List<string> categories = new List<string>();` in which I am saving only names of categories. How can I save second list to the same XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add it the same way you are currently doing it, but you would have a root element that holds the two lists.

```
var xEle = new XElement("Parent");
xEle.Add(new XElement("Child"));
xEle.Add(new XElement("Child2"));
```